# Passing Managedbean property

Tags: jsf-2.2

I've two session scoped beans I need to pass values between them through  f:setPropertyActionListener  but I cant read it from receivable end.

```
<p:selectOneListbox style="height: 100%; width: 100%" id="lstSubject" required="true" requiredMessage="Please select any Subject" 
    value="#{chooseSubExamManagedBean.subId}" >
    <f:selectItems value="#{chooseSubExamManagedBean.mapSubjects}" />
</p:selectOneListbox>
```

user chooses the subject and I've to pass this id from p:command button to another bean

```
<p:commandButton  id="cmdProceed" value="Proceed" action="#{chooseSubExamManagedBean.gotoFillMarks}" >
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{fillMarksManagedBean.subId}" value="#{chooseSubExamManagedBean.subId}" />
</p:commandButton>
```

the managed bean fillMarksManagedBean

```
@Named(value = "fillMarksManagedBean")
@javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped
public class FillMarksManagedBean implements Serializable{
private int SubId;
private String ExamDetail;

    public void setSubId(int SubId) {
        this.SubId = SubId;
    }

    public int getSubExamId() {
        return SubExamId;
    }
```

and use that subId in

```
@PostConstruct
    public void init() {

    ExamDetail = clsFillMarks.getExamDetail(SubId);
}
...
```

How do i do this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: In other words, you expected the `init()` method to be invoked **after** the `<f:setPropertyActionListener>` has executed? Why and how exactly?

Comment: Yes. I Want to get the selected value in second page and process it in @PostConstruct. If I want to do this is there another way.

Comment: But the `@PostConstruct` is invoked when bean is created for the first time in its scope(!) which happens **before** the `<f:setPropertyActionListener>` is executed. The reason is very logical: you cannot set a property in a bean which is not constructed.

Comment: Ok, then how should I do this? I want to pass selected value to next bean and process it before page display.

Comment: You normally perform actions in action(listener) methods.

Comment: can you provide sample code or link? BTW if I set the bean in faces-config.xml and pass values through `<managed-property>` it works as I excepted.